# Connect Sql Server database to Android Application using web services

Tags: android, sql-server, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I wanted to connect to Sql Server database using android application so that I can store data and retrieve data in Sql Sever using some code written in Java for Android Application... How can I do that thing.. Any tutorials or links will be appreciated..

Comment: @OMG Ponies, Can you please read the question again.. I have ask for any kind of tutorials or links that can explain the above concept because I don't know how to do it .. I haven't ask for the code written by you..

Comment: @success_anil, thanks for the information.. I will keep that in mind..Any idea how can I do this..??

Comment: Also is your java application is server application or standalone java application ?

Comment: @success_anil, its a Standalone Java Application..

Comment: @OP Can't you please use a search engine?

Comment: @Chris, I tried searching.. I posted here so that I can have some better link from you guys, who are working on that or have worked on that.. As I haven'r worked on that till now.. SO that;s why I was asking for help.. So there is no point for downvoting it.. As it is not necessary you will get the everything whatever you are looking for.

Comment: @OP why don't you work on it a bit more before posting a question on SO?  Considering you just started working on it now, the 'question does not show any research effort' button is seeming attractive.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/androidosbeginning/cosuming-restful-webservice-in-android  Please refer the link for consuming restful webservices in android.

Comment: @TechGeeky they won't help atleast and instead they downvote the questions. I always start to feel that they just don't know anything. well, leave these guys. did you get answer to your question, coz I'm too in need of it. So please help with any link.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know in case of android you have to rely on Http for interacting with a server or open a socket to you java application and invoke method on it and pass and get data from it. Directly you can't access sql server db.

Comment: thanks for the response.. Do you have any link or tutorials, that can explain the concepts.. That will be great help for me..

Comment: Please refer this link http://relsellglobal.info/kshare/2011/06/connecting-to-http-server-from-android-application/